# Как создать exe файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код, который с помощью `tkinter`-а получает входные данные и формирует отчет (результат кода: создается один `txt` и один `xls` файл). Код работает, но когда я конвертирую его в `exe` файл (библиотека `pyinstaller`, еще попробовал `auto-py-to-exe` тоже не получилось) файл создается, но не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
import tkinter as tk
def get_data():
    date1 = dateFrom.get()
    date2= dateTo.get()
    from pathlib import Path
    print("Начало даты")

    print("Конец даты")


    import os
    import pandas as pd

    mylist=[]
    for path in Path().glob('ot-*.log'):
        if f'ot-{date1}.log' <= path.name <= f'ot-{date2}.log':
            mylist.append(path.name)


    import re
    from datetime import datetime

    with open('final.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        for fname in mylist:
            file_date = fname.replace('ot-', '').replace('.log', '')
            with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(file_date + ' ' + line)



    sessions = {}

    data = []

    with open('final.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        log = f.readlines()


    for line in log:

        if 'Login successful' in line:
            chunks = re.search(r"(.+?) Login successful from user (.+?) from .+ session=(.+?) .+", line)

    
            login_time = datetime.strptime(chunks.group(1), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')

            sessions[chunks.group(3)] = {'login_time': login_time, 'username': chunks.group(2)}

        elif 'Closing session' in line:
    
            chunks = re.search(r'(.+?) Closing session.+session=(.+?) .+', line)

            logout_time = datetime.strptime(chunks.group(1), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
            session_id = chunks.group(2)

            if session_id not in sessions:
                print('Сессия {} закрыта, нет данных о входе'.format(session_id))
            else:
                login_time = sessions[session_id]['login_time']
                username = sessions[session_id]['username']
                session_time = logout_time - login_time
                #print('Пользователь {} зашел в {}, вышел в {}. Время сеанса- {} . ID сессии- {}'.format(username, login_time, logout_time, session_time, session_id))
                data.append([username, login_time,logout_time, session_id, session_time ])  
                del sessions[session_id]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['user_name', 'login', 'logout', 'session id', 'session_time' ])
    df.to_excel("test.xlsx")

win=tk.Tk()
dateFrom = tk.Entry(win)
dateFrom.grid(row=0,column=1)

dateTo=tk.Entry(win)
dateTo.grid(row=1,column=1)
tk.Button(win, text="Report", command=get_data).grid(row=2,column=1)
```

Comment: Выдаёт какую-то ошибку?

Comment: Одна из самых частых проблем с pyinstaller и также auto-py-to-exe это сжатие вложенных DLL с помощью UPX, у меня это часто не работало, поэтому я всегда отключаю это сжатие, добавляя флаг `--noupx`, попробуйте. Этот флаг надо в pyinstaller команду добавлять. Также в auto-py-to-exe интерфейсе этот флаг где то есть как птичка, если нет, то в интерфейсе есть также окошко где можно задать дополнительные флаги произвольные, вот надо туда добавить `--noupx`.

Comment: Не работал с tkinter а импорты точно должны быть так раскиданы, может верх перенести и после этого сработает? это первое чтобы я бы поробовал в этом случае

Comment: @Farid Мне удалось ваше приложение упаковать в EXE и успешно запустить и оно работает, оформил моё решение в [моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1223539/267338), пожалуйста посмотрите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следующие шаги позволили мне успешно построить EXE приложение используя свежий PyInstaller на Python 3.7 64-bit и Windows 10 64-bit, и это приложение в итоге запускалось и работало:

1. Добавить в конец скрипта (в последнюю строку) `tk.mainloop()`. Возможно этого вообще у вас будет достаточно для работы. Если нет, выполните остальные шаги.
2. Использовать только Python версии `3.7` или меньше, если у вас его нет то установите. PyInstaller официально ещё не поддерживает Python `3.8` и больше. Хотя он инсталлируется на эти версии но в итоге не всегда или плохо работает.
3. В питоне 3.7 обновить PyInstaller до последней версии, следующей командой `C:\bin\Python37\python -m pip install --upgrade pyinstaller`, где `C:\bin\Python37\python` это полный путь к питону 3.7, для примера это путь на моём компьютере, на вашем папка будет отличаться.
4. В папке где лежит ваш скрипт (допустим он называется `script.py`) выполнить команду `C:\bin\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile --noupx script.py`, где `C:\bin\Python37\` это полный путь с установкой питона 3.7, на вашем компьютере будет другая папка.
5. В папке рядом со скриптом появится папка `dist/` в ней будет `script.exe`, это запускной файл финальный, вся программа это один EXE файл. Запускайте его и пробуйте. У меня такие шаги производят рабочий и успешно выполняющийся EXE.

Comment: Добавил tk.mainloop() и все сработало. Спасибо

Comment: @Farid Кстати я заметил важный момент ещё. Когда я использовал питон 3.7 то у меня EXE получился около 40МБ. А когда питон 3.8 то 250МБ. Так что тоже обратите внимание на это, если у вас питон 3.8 и большой EXE, то просто попробуйте питон 3.7.

Comment: У меня сейчас 30МБ. Думаю если использовать 3.7 будет меньше, но не пробовал. Спасибо за советы